# Should I resize a window on language change

Tags: gui-design, desktop-application, internationalisation

In my desktop I have a settings dialog that after I change the app language there's a label text gets too big for its space. I want to know if it is good practice to resize the window after a language change in case something goes out alignment in that particular language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a better experience for the user to see a dialog that appropriately fits its contents, vs. making text smaller or having labels overflow their containers. It also gives the user a sense that the application is written for them, rather than geared toward a language they might not speak.

Comment: So your answer is yes, i should resize?

Comment: Yes, you should resize the container to match the content.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do do